# When does a deprecated field in a MongoDB document get deleted?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I use NodeJS, MongoDB, and Mongoose. I changed a field from a string to a string array. A month ago, I had:

```js
// Before.
const UserSchema = new Schema({
  ip: String
});
```

Since last week, I have:

```
// After.
const UserSchema = new Schema({
  ips: [String]
});
```

Because of my daily scripts where I do save the field, now none of the documents have the field `ip`. I assume that when NodeJS loads a user object, it uses the latest schema; when it saves the object, it overwrites any previous document. So I expect that the previous field `ip` would not survive an update with `user.save()`.

Is that true? If NodeJS only loads a document and does not save it, would it retain the original `ip` field?

**Update**: Following the comment suggested, I ended up with a document that contains both versions:

```
> db.users.find({ip: {$ne: null}}, {ip: 1, ips: 1}).pretty()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5f065633404c3e4aaac69142"), "ip" : "::1" }
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5f30773f86a1993db449e1b3"),
    "ip" : "::1",
    "ips" : [
        "::1"
    ]
}
```

If it contains `ips`, then it has saved the object with the new schema. So I don't understand when the original field `ip` was overwritten.

Comment: Test it and find out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a bit of poking, the deprecated field does not get deleted, but I was unable to access it from NodeJS because it was missing from the schema. Here is an example of a static method:

```js
// Get all users.
UserSchema.statics.getAllUsers = function() {
  try {
    // Return all users.
    return User.find()
      .sort({created: -1})
      .exec();
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
};

UserSchema.statics.inspect = async function() {
  let users = await this.getAllUsers();

  for (let user of users) {
    console.log("IP = " + user.ip);
    console.log("user = " + user.toString());
  }
  return;
}
```

The result is:

```
IP = undefined
user = {
  _id: 5f4e7...,
  ip: '::ffff:...',
 ...
}
```

So the deprecated field did not get deleted. When I added it back in the Mongoose schema, I was able to access it again from NodeJS code.

Answer (score 0):

just add new ip to `ips` fields using `push` method. go through this examples

```js
const user = require('../your model');

const findingUser = await user.findOne(id);

const updateUser  = findingUser.ips.push(newIp);

updateUser.save()
```

now it wouldn't overwrite, adding new IPs instead.

Comment: Yes, this code works and I was able to save the recovered data in the array. I'm more interested in the mechanics of how documents are saved and overwritten in MongoDB.